# InvalidObjectException when looking up EJB3 on WAS7

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.0, websphere-7

I have a java web application that is deployed in two EARs - one for the UI tier (contains a `WAR module`) and one for the business tier (contains an `EJB module`). Both tiers are deployed to WebSphere Application Server 7. The tiers are connected via EJB 3.0 stateless session beans. The beans are looked up via JNDI.

The two applications are currently on the same WAS server, but in the future will be deployed onto different servers. When I attempt to lookup an EJB, I get an error.

Attempting to debug the lookup error, I ran a JNDI namespace dump on the WAS server:

```
./dumpNameSpace.bat -host localhost -port 10031 > namespace.log
```

Each of my EJBs was listed with the following error:

```
(top)/nodes/U4752879Node01/servers/server1/ejb/au/gov/immi/emed/ejb/CrtEJB
                                               au.gov.immi.emed.ejb.CrtEJB
ERROR: Received the following naming exception: com.ibm.ws.naming.util.InvalidObjectException: The IOR associated with the binding "CrtEJB" relative to the context "U4752879Node01Cell/nodes/U4752879Node01/servers/server1/ejb/au/gov/immi/emed/ejb" could not be resolved.  If the binding is for an application object, make sure the application has started successfully. IOR: IOR:<removed>
```

Here is the EJB remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface CrtEJB extends EMedEJB, EMedCrtService
{
}
```

And the bean implementation:

```
@Stateless(name = "CrtEJB")
@Remote(value = CrtEJB.class)
public class CrtEJBBean extends AbstractEMedEJBBean implements CrtEJB
{

    ...
}
```

And the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd">
    <session name="CrtEJB" simple-binding-name="ejb/au/gov/immi/emed/ejb/CrtEJB" />
        ...
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

What is causing the error to occur? The error is the same without the `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file, which I shound't need. Is this error what's causing the UI lookup to fail, or should that be working anyway? (in which case I'll post the UI error).

Comment: I would guess the EJB failed to start.  Does the server-side show any error messages for the relevant EJB?

Comment: I don't know how I missed it, as that was my first thought and I'd checked the server logs multiple times. I checked again and the EJB remote interface is getting a ClassNotFoundException for one of its interfaces. I imagine it will be fixed once I resolve that, thanks.